# Rescaling a picture when editing a post

Tags: support, formatting, editing, answers

Is there any simple way of changing the dimensions of a picture when adding it to a post? (Other than downloading and change it in an editor.)
Sometimes the default size of the image I find is not good for the readability of what I am writing.

//Unrelated, is meta the right place for this type of questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If you upload the image using the image dialog so it's hosted by *imgur*, you can change the name of the image to display resized ones that are automatically generated on upload:

- Add `l` at the end of the image name for a 640 pixels in width *large* image,
- add `m` for a 320 pixels wide *medium* image,
- `t` for a 160 pixels wide *tiny* image,
- or `s` for a *small* 90x90 pixels thumbnail

Mind that these file name suffixes are case sensitive!

---

For example, [`https://i.stack.imgur.com/sI5O0.jpg`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sI5O0.jpg) is a fairly large image. By adding those letters to its file name, we can get:

- 640 px wide [`sI5O0l.jpg`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sI5O0l.jpg) (large):

  [image: 640px]
- 320 px wide [`sI5O0m.jpg`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sI5O0m.jpg) (medium):

  [image: 320px]
- 160 px wide [`sI5O0t.jpg`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sI5O0t.jpg) (tiny):

  [image: 160px]
- 90x90 px [`sI5O0s.jpg`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sI5O0s.jpg) (small thumbnail):

  [image: 90x90px]

Comment: Very useful to know. Anyway of changing it after it is added? (Without deleting it and trying to remember where you found the image)